# Waiting for specific message in gRPC stream of messages in Gatling load scripts

Tags: grpc, gatling

What I have: gRPC endpoint which sends a stream of message updates in response.

What I want to test: I want to create a load test that will open a stream, get multiple messages until a message with a specific field will not be captured (within defined timeout). (Without an explicit call of pause method and waiting for some time).

What I get from Gatling-gRPC:
After an explicit call of pause() method, the reconciliation method is returning the last captured message.

Example server: [here](https://github.com/alexromanov/server-grpc-sample)
Protofile: [here](https://github.com/alexromanov/server-grpc-sample/blob/main/src/main/protobuf/hello_world.proto)

Test code:

```
package load.api

import com.github.phisgr.gatling.generic.SessionCombiner
import com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.Predef._
import example.myapp.helloworld.grpc.hello_world.{GreeterServiceGrpc, HelloRequest}
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.grpc.{CallOptions, Status}

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.language.postfixOps

class StreamSim extends Simulation {
  val greetCall = grpc("Greet")
    .serverStream("greeter")

  val scn = scenario(s"Greet Flow")
   .exec(greetCall.start(GreeterServiceGrpc.METHOD_IT_KEEPS_REPLYING)
    (HelloRequest("THIS IS TEST MESSAGE"))
      .extract(_.some.get.message.some)(_ saveAs "message")
      .sessionCombiner(SessionCombiner.pick("message"))
      .endCheck(statusCode is Status.Code.OK)
    )
    .pause(10 seconds)
    .exec(greetCall.copy(requestName = "Reconciliate greet").reconciliate)
    .exec { session =>
      println(s"%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%> Last character of the message: ${session.attributes("message")}")
      session
    }


  setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(1) during (10 seconds))
    .protocols(grpc(managedChannelBuilder(name = "127.0.0.1", port = 8080).usePlaintext()).shareChannel.disableWarmUp))
}
```

Comment: It does seem that what you want to do is not supported. Feel free to create an feature request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @GeorgeLeung - here is the [feature request](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/issues/50).